# socket: address family not supported by protocol

Tags: docker, centos7

**CentOS 7**

Docker version **20.10.6**, build 370c289

I try to run image like this:

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -v sonarqube-conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf -v sonarqube-data:/opt/sonarqube/data -v sonarqube-logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs -v sonarqube-extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions sonarqube
```

But get error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint sonarqube (asfsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfds): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp6 [::]:9000: socket: address family not supported by protocol.
```

Comment: Looks like ipv6 is not enabled on your Centos host.

Answer (score 4):

This [blog post](https://www.redelijkheid.com/blog/2021/4/14/docker-images-not-starting) discusses the problem and solution:

> For some reason IPv6 (the hint is tcp6) is screwing things up. The problem is that I disabled IPv6 from the start on this host. Mainly because of some concerns in regards of routing and internet accessibility (I have a formal IPv6 subnet at home).

In your case, this is the solution which worked for a container of mine where I was seeing the same issue. Replace the host port with the host LAN IPv4 address (I used 172.16.18.93 in the following snippet) and port:

```sh
docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 172.16.18.93:9000:9000 -v sonarqube-conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf -v sonarqube-data:/opt/sonarqube/data -v sonarqube-logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs -v sonarqube-extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions sonarqube
```

Comment: Binding to `-p 0.0.0.0:9000:9000` will work as well.

Comment: For me it actually worked after enabling IPV6, actually deleting the ipv6 disabling values from GRUB on linux, and restarting machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

Install Docker ver **20.10.5**

```
 E.g. from repo:
sudo yum install docker-ce-20.10.5 docker-ce-cli-20.10.5 containerd.io
```

And now problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

so for those that run in to this issue, the thing that solved it for me was to update docker

reviewing the documentation, just grab the latest release of docker. https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

i.e

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```